# Ajax function not calling

Tags: angularjs, ajax, web-services

I am trying to call web service using ajax call in AngularJS Application and want to display data. But its not reaching to function. what is the problem.

**AJAX Call-**

```
function EmpCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.getEmployee = function () {
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "EmpWebService.asmx/GetEmployee",
          data: "{}",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function (msg) {
              $(msg).find('Table').each(function (i, row) {

                  $scope.Name = $(row).find('empName').text();
                  $scope.Age = $(row).find('empAge').text();
                  $scope.City = $(row).find('empCity').text();

              });
          }
      });
  };
}
```

Here is my **web service**

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string  GetEmployee()
    {
        string connectionStr =       ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionStr"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionStr);
        SqlCommand cmd;
       DataTable dt;

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from Emp_TempTbl";
           using(SqlDataAdapter sda=new SqlDataAdapter (cmd))
           {
               using (DataSet ds=new DataSet ())
               {
                   sda.Fill(ds);
                   return ds.GetXml();
               }
           } 
        }
        catch(Exception) 
        {
            throw;
        }
```

And here is **Angular JS UI**

```
<html  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="myApp">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script>
        angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('EmpCtrl', EmpCtrl);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" ng-controller="EmpCtrl" ng-submit="save()">
        <div style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 12px; margin-left: 450px;">
                  <div>
                <input type="button" id="btnFetch" value="Fetch" ng-click="getEmployee()" />
            </div>

        </div>
        <hr />

        <table border="1" style="text-align: center; margin-left: 410px;">
            <tr>

                <td> Name
                </td>
                <td> Age
                </td>              
                <td>City
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>{{Name}}
                </td>
                <td>{{Age}}
                </td>      
                <td>{{City}}
                </td>
           </tr>
       </table>
       </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: in angularjs you should use $http.post mehtod https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Did your post call executes successfully or not  ?

Comment: i have gone through same way while saving data in DB with   $scope.save = function () {code here} and its working. And '$http.post' is still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change controller to :

```
function EmpCtrl($scope, $http) {
        var post_data = {};
        var responsePromise = $http.post("EmpWebService.asmx/GetEmployee", post_data);
        responsePromise.success(function(msg, status1, headers, config) {
            $(msg).find('Table').each(function (i, row) {
                $scope.Name = $(row).find('empName').text();
                $scope.Age = $(row).find('empAge').text();
                $scope.City = $(row).find('empCity').text();

              });
        });
};
```